# Symfony2 - Collection + jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I use collection type with symfony:

When I choose value in select. This value is add in list but I don't know how to make this with symfony collection.

Here my html output:

```
<div id="equipe_joueurs" class="mes_joueurs"
data-prototype="
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="equipe_joueurs___name__">__name__label__</label>
<select id="equipe_joueurs___name__" name="equipe[joueurs][__name__]" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>           
    <option value="1" >Joueur1</option>           
    <option value="2" >Joueur2</option>           
    <option value="3" >Joueur3</option>
</select>
```

Here my js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var container = $('#equipe_joueurs');

        var index = container.find(':input').length;

        var prototype = $(container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g).replace(/__name__/g, index));

        $('#equipe_joueurs').change(function()
        {
            var prototype = $(container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g).replace(/__name__/g, index));

            $('#equipe_list').append('<li id="equipe_joueur_' + index + '" name="equipe[joueurs][' + index + ']">' + 'prototype.text() + '</li>');
            index++;
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Finally, I custom my twig and I append all my elements in this new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="list"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#list').append(prototype)
```